# How to wait for a thread to finish before starting more in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

So say that I have 10 things to run, but I can only have 3 threads running at a time.

```
ArrayList<NewThread> threads = new ArrayList<NewThread>();

for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
   NewThread t = new NewThread(args[i]);
   threads.add(newThread);

   if( (i%3) == 0) {
      for (NewThread nt : threads) {
         nt.join();
      }
      threads.clear();
   }
}
```

The class NewThreads implements Runnable.  I thought the join() method would work to make it wait for the threads to finish before looping around again and kicking off the next batch of threads, but instead I get a stack overflow exception.  I think I am implementing join() incorrectly, but I am unsure how to do it.  I currently am doing it as

```
public void join() {
   this.join();
}
```

in my NewThread class.  Any suggestions on how to get this working or a better way to go about it?

Comment: What about using Thread Pools and SingleThreadExecutor ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: Well, that's just a simple mistake: remove the whole join method:

Comment: If you haven't started a thread you probably don't want to wait for it to join. `t.start()` then `t.join()`.

Comment: @StoneBird Sorry I couldn't include my full code for the NewThread class, but it is already calling t.start() in its contructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simple mistake.

Remove the method

```
    public void join() {
      this.join();
    }
```

This method calls itself again and again.
NewThread should extend Thread.

Or 2nd way:

keep the method and call

```
     Thread.currentThread.join();
```

The rest looks fine.

Answer (score 5):

You are implementins or overriding join to call itself endlessly

```
public void join() {
   this.join(); // call myself until I blow up.
}
```

The simplest solution is to use Thread.join() already there, but a better solution is to use a fixed size thread pool so you don't have to start and stop threads which can waste a lot of time and code.

You can use an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    es.submit(new Task(i));
```